# Running Mount Script at Ubuntu Startup

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, startup, expect

I have this script to automount my BoxCryptor folder (Dropbox encryption) in Ubuntu.  Everything works fine when I run it from the command line, but...when I place this in my "Startup Applications" it doesn't work.

Contents of boxcryptor-automount.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
sleep 3
set timeout 1
spawn encfs /home/j/Dropbox/Encrypted.bc/ /home/j/BoxCryptor
expect 'EncFS Password:'
send "mypassword\r"
interact
```

Command line in Ubuntu Startup Applications:

```
/usr/bin/expect /home/j/boxcryptor-auto/boxcryptor-automount.sh
```

Any ideas?  I have it listed last in the Startup Applications List (I put a z in front of the Name figuring maybe it needed to run last, but that didn't help).  BTW, its Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue I had was that special characters in the password were being treated as plain text, such as the '$' which needed to be '\$'